# issue while adding kendo grid module

Tags: module, package, kendo-ui, grid, ivy

facing the below issue, tried all different types of solutions  ./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):

tried deleting nodemodules, modifying complier options and ng add kendo grid module